# Loader is used without the corresponding plugin - Angular 2 with Webpack

Tags: angular, webkit

I did just as in the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) page for webpack, and I get following error

> ERROR in ./public/css/styles.css
>   Module build failed: Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin, refer to https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin for the usage example
>       at Object.module.exports.pitch (/home/vandavv/WebstormProjects/testWebKit/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js:21:9)
>    @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 12:0-38

Here's my repo (**EDIT**. repo does not longer exists, but it was cloned from documentation) with this code, only thing diffrent from docks is that I didn't add tests (but app should be working even without them)

I have no idea why it is broken and how could that be that example in documentation is not working

I'm using node 6.3.1 and npm 3.x.x

**EDIT**
Angular was in rc5 in that time, so it may be a badly written documentation in some place

Answer (score -2):

I can not see you repo, but i came into this problem before. If you use `extract-text-webpack-plugin` correctly, there is a possible reason that if you want to extract less and scss file into two css files, you have to make sure that this plugin added twice. see [here](https://github.com/liangklfangl/react-universal-bucket). If you use bootstrap-loader, you may come into this one

Comment: here is question about angular2 your demo is on reactjs.